# Failed to send report using Crashrpt

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smtp, crashrpt

I have intergrated Crashrpt in my VC++ MFC application to handle exceptions. It's working fine and shows dialog to send error, but when I press send error button to send mail, it fails. I am using following gmail SMTP settings for testing:

```
SMTP Host : smtp.gmail.com
SMTP Port : 587
```

I think it requires SSL enabled to send mail, but in Crashrpt I can't find any option to enable SSL. It gives following error while sending mail :

```
Sending AUTH LOGIN.
SendMsg : pszMessage(AUTH LOGIN )
SendMsg : res(13)
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. i10sm70198106pat.11 - gsmtp
```

Please someone guide me, I am very stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Crash report can't handle TLS, as it says in the info: "CrashRpt has a simple built-in SMPT [sic] client". I would also suggest that you probably don't want to be putting SMTP login information into an app if you're deploying it externally.

Have you tried the HTTP option? It's very simple to create a web page to receive the error and then forward it to you in an email.

To set it up you need to add it to the priorities and specify a URL, e.g.

```
info.uPriorities[CR_HTTP] = 3;
info.pszUrl = _T("http://my.web.site/crashrpt.aspx");
```

Comment: I have no idea about HTTP option, can you please give any example ?

Comment: It's one of the delivery options: info.uPriorities[CR_HTTP]. I'll modify the answer.